# Optimizing / replacing multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

I want to call the same function when the user presses any of the arrow keys. I am able to achieve it with samething like this:

```js
if (x.style.display = "block" && 
     (event.keyCode === 37 || 
      event.keyCode === 38 || 
      event.keyCode === 39 || 
      event.keyCode === 40)
   ) 
   { ...}
```

I just wonder if there is a more elegant way of achieving this, maybe with less code.

Comment: `if (keyCode => 37 && keyCode <= 40)` or if the values are not a range: `if ([37, 39, 41, 43].includes(keyCode))` (note that the fact that this is about keydowns or calling a function is irrelevant to the issue, which is optimizing/replacing multiple conditions, i.e. the question title is misleading)

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. I learnt a lot. I also edited the title to something more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (![37,38,39,40].includes(e.keyCode)) return
  
  console.log('arrow key pressed')
})
```

Or you can check the range.

Answer (score 1):

U can also use Array.indexOf()

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', e  =>  {
  if (![37,38,39,40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) 
    return  console.log('arrow key pressed')
})
```